# Bootstrapping Geth on Ropsten Testnet with Known Nodes

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, ropsten

I tried syncing with the Ropsten testnet using Geth with the following command.

```
 geth --testnet --mine --minerthreads=1
```

When it looks from Geth like I'm synced, the block height is way behind what it shows on https://ropsten.etherscan.io/ and I have either no peers or very few.  Is there a way to give Geth a few known peers to bootstrap it onto the "right" Ropsten testnet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like [this](https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten#ropsten-testnet-pow-chain).

```
geth --testnet --fast --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303"
```